# Database query data to string in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an query like

```
SELECT EmployeeName FROM Employee
```

Query result will be :

```
Mr. Kamal
Mr. Karim
Mr. Rahim
Mr. Jamal
```

But I need :

```
Mr. Kamal , Mr. Karim, Mr. Rahim, Mr. Jamal
```

Is it possible with a single query.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Once you get the results using a query you can process it and do what ever you want in code. simple you can convert the result to an array in this specific case, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
# DATA SOURCE NAME
$dsn = "dbi:mysql:$database:localhost:3306";

# PERL DBI CONNECT
$connect = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);

# PREPARE THE QUERY
$query = "SELECT EmployeeName FROM  Employee ORDER BY id";
$query_handle = $connect->prepare($query);

# EXECUTE THE QUERY
$query_handle->execute();

# BIND TABLE COLUMNS TO VARIABLES
 $query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$id);

 # LOOP THROUGH RESULTS
 while($query_handle->fetch()) {
   print "$employeeName" ,;
}
```